# Anyone going to the World Open?

Tags: discussion

Along the lines of [site promotion](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/106/12), probably not a bad place to hang up posters, talk, etc.

And it would be fun to meet people!

Comment: I'm not going (never been), but you should definitely try to spread the word there.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a year late, but I'm going down to DC today for the 2013 World Open :)