# Suggestions for Attracting New Users

Tags: discussion, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What avenues of site promotion do we have available?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-avenues-of-site-promotion-do-we-have-available)

Do you guys have any suggestions for attracting new users? We seem to have a total of 47 avid users at this point and all our metrics are pretty low except for "answers". I have seen the thread for advertising on the other SE sites, but I think it might be wise to talk about some ways that we might advertise on other sites. Suggestions?

Comment: Good question, already asked: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/106/167

Comment: I'm going to close this one so we can keep all discussion concentrated at the earlier question (which I've now "featured", so thanks to Robert for bumping this in my mind).